# cannot get results from an asp.net page to be used in the jquery token input drop-down

Tags: jquery, asp.net

please help me I'm stuck here for a long time with no solution, I'm trying to use the jQuery token input to display selection result from an asp.net page, the page is called correctly and it generates the right JSON form, but the result didn't appear in the drop-down list, here is the code of the input field in the HTML,

```
<div>
        <input type="text" id="textBox2" name="blah2" runat="server"/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#textBox2").tokenInput("Default.aspx", {
                    theme: "facebook"
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

and the code of the aspx page is something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        string searchParam = Request.QueryString["q"];
        Country country = new Country();
        country.name = searchParam;
        country.id = searchParam;
        List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();
        countryList.Add(country);
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string serialized = serializer.Serialize(countryList);
        Response.Write(serialized);
    }
```

is there any thing more i should do,
please help,
thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the token input to call a webservice instead of an aspx page and it worked well for me..

Answer (score 0):

Add `Response.End()` method call at the end of the `Page_Load`

By the way, for server controls use following selector for id: `$("#<%= textBox2.ClientID %>")`

Comment: I've tried your solution but also nothing happens, actually I solved this issue using another approach, I've used the token input to call a webservice not an aspx page and it worked well for me...